# Trying to get Isotope masonry working on my site

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to incorporate Isotope into a site I'm coding and not able to get it to work the way I expected.  The goal is to create columns of content boxes that will have a relative width (for now it's 28%) and a variable height, depending on the amount of content in the box.
I want the boxes aligned into columns and have each box directly under the one above, masonry style.
Testing my code on the site being built yielded no result, as can be seen here: http://bruggemann.us/
So I copied my code into codepen to try and work it out, and got a different result, albeit still not the result I'm looking for.  That is at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adGJmY
For reference, I'm using in my code:

```
<script src="web/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="web/js/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="web/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

I've looked at the documentation and looked at other codepen samples, and can't find an answer to what I may be missing.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: use imageloaded js http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js . `$('.contentwrap').imagesLoaded( function() { //here your isotope code }`

Comment: I didn't find that you  call the isotype like `$('.contentblock').isotope({` in the view source

Comment: The call is there in the JS panel at codepen.

Comment: Yes, the code at codepen was copied from my site, except for the content in the boxes.  I just updated the site to use images loaded, but it's made no difference.

Comment: issue in codepen line `columnWidth: '.contentbox-sizer'` in  `masonry: {
   columnWidth: '.contentbox-sizer'
  }` just remove it and run the codepen once

Comment: Updated codepen, removing columnwidth.  Now it looks just like my site, as in still not correct.  Your suggestion below isn't working.  Nesting of isotope inside imagesloaded is giving me a syntax error.  I can't figure a fix to the syntax for that.

Comment: see http://codepen.io/tamilcselvan/pen/WrJjGX

Comment: In your codepen, in css .contentbox-sizer change width to 8% and  `masonry: {}` http://codepen.io/tamilcselvan/pen/wMjdoq

Comment: I updated my codepen and it is working in codepen.  Ironically, I made the changes on my site first and it didn't work.  I copied my code to codepen, and it worked.  I went back and mad sure all updates were uploaded and am still not getting the same result on my site that I get in Codepen.  Don't know why.  I'm going to sleep it off and try again tomorrow.  Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply,  you are loading the imagesloaded function before the imagesloaded.js script is loaded and you have commented out the isotope script so it is never loaded, so you get the error.

Your code is this:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="web/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- Code from file inserted below  <script src="web/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js">   </script>
-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.contentblock').isotope({
        // options
        percentPosition: true,
        itemSelector: '.contentbox',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: '.contentbox-sizer'
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script src="web/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

You need to add  imagesloaded before you call the functions and uncomment the  isotope script:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="web/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="web/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<script src="web/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js">   </script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.contentblock').isotope({
        // options
        percentPosition: true,
        itemSelector: '.contentbox',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: '.contentbox-sizer'
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are correct in what you've stated. In the attempt to boil down the code to it's simplest so I could try to figure out what was wrong, I mistakenly commented out the isotope script file. Which led me to what the original issue was. My function was in a separate js file, and I failed to include it in a script tag. I've put my original code back together and ensured I have a pointer to my js file, and it works. So, I have to apologize to those who assisted for wasting your time.  It was my own stupid mistake, and as sometimes happens, it is one of the most obvious things that get overlooked.